# Update value in nested dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary as follows:

```
gP = dict.fromkeys(range(6), {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None})
```

Now, when I try to modify a value doing:

```
gP[0]['a'] = 1
```

for some reason, all the values of `a` (regardless of the key they belong to) change to 1 as shown below:

```
{0: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 1: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 2: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 3: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 4: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None},
 5: {'a': 1, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}}
```

What I am doing wrong? What's the proper assignment statement?

Comment: You're only creating *one dict*. Python doesn't make copies of it for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I don't understand how to fix it from your answer, @deceze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @deceze said, Python doesn't make copies. You are referencing the same dict in all the value parts of the key-value pairs.

An alternative would be:

```
gP = {x: {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None} for x in range(6)}
```

**Update**: There is a much cleaner version of this answer by [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands):

```
{x: dict.fromkeys('abcd') for x in range(6)}
```

Comment: Shorter would be `{x: dict.fromkeys('abcd') for x in range(6)}`; or probably faster to take the `dict.fromkeys` outside the loop

Comment: @Chris_Rands: You should probably put that out as a separate answer. I like it better than mine. :)

Comment: You can add it to your answer :)

Comment: Please post someone, It's a nice attempt.