# Updating value of a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary

users={'user502':{'firstname':'James' , 'lastname':'Jones'}}

User can search for first or last name and be able to update to something else. I wrote the following code:

```
name_change=input('Enter name to change: ')
for key,value in users.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        if name_change==v:
            #print('name found in', value.get(name_change))
            #print('name found in', value.get(k))
            print('name found in', k)
            updated_name=input('What would be the new name: ')
            users.update(k=updated_name)
            break
        else:
            print('name not found')
```

I am getting RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration error. I did some research on update and also looked at this stackoverflow discussion [Update value in nested dictionary - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513825/update-value-in-nested-dictionary-python)

I am not able to figure out how to point the code to pick first name or last name based on whatever user enters. Some hints would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

**From other discussion it seems like in Python 3 it does not work because of '3.x because keys returns an iterator instead of a list.'
I tried to do a pop first and then update

```
updated_name=input('What would be the new name: ')
           # users[k][v]=updated_name
            x= value.get(k)
            users.pop(x)
            users[x]=updated_name
```

However now I get KeyError: 'James'

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do. Can you give an example of what an updated dictionary would look like?

Comment: Enter name to change: James
name found in firstname
What would be the new name: Jimmy   

users={'user502':{'firstname':'Jimmy','lastname':'Jones'}}

Comment: Basically user wants to change first or last name from the original dictionary where the values are :

{'user502':{'firstname':'James' , 'lastname':'Jones'}}

Comment: In that case, your second example should probably be modifying value, not users

Comment: but why would you want to modify a parameter across all users in the first place??

Comment: Think about this, you have a phone book. A contact changed  last name or may be first name. You have updated the old name. Now you want to see the directory, which should show you the updated value. After changing the names when I print users dictionary, I expect to see the updated value.

Comment: Your code will, once you fix it, change every item, across every user, whose value is "james" to "jimmy". Is that really the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

This code is doing what I wanted. May be my question was not clear sorry about that

```
print('Actual-', users)
name_change=input('Enter name to change: ')
for key,value in users.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        if name_change==v:
            #print('name found in', value.get(name_change))
            #print('name found in', value.get(k))
            print('name found in', k)
            updated_name=input('What would be the new name: ')
            value[k]=updated_name
            break
        else:
            print('name not found')

    print("modified name:", users)
```

Output:

```
Actual- {'user502': {'lastname': 'Jones', 'firstname': 'James'}}
Enter name to change: Jones
name found in lastname
What would be the new name: January
modified name: {'user502': {'lastname': 'January', 'firstname': 'James'}}
```